# Flutter: How can I limit children width of SliverChildListDelegate?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project in which `SliverList` is used inside a `CustomScrollView`. The `SliverList` has its `delegate` property set to `SliverChildListDelegate`. The `SliverChildListDelegate` is populated with widgets that have their width set to 200. On building the app the widgets take the width of the whole app regardless. If these same widgets are put in a `Column` under `SingleChildScrollView` the width is respected and set to 200. How can I limit the with of the children widgets inside `SliverChildListDelegate`?

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a trick than an official solution. I just wrap it with `Row` and put that `Widget` in between 2 `Spacer`s. E.g:

```dart
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
    Row(
      children: [
        Spacer(),
        Container(
          height: 6,
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    ),
  ]),
)
```

Comment: It is causing overflow issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

just only wraping the widget inside a Row, will solve the issue.